# Is there a max record count in HSQL for 'addScript'?

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I currently am spinning up an HSQL DB in-memory to play with some data and not actually need to query against my DEV DB.

So I have the following setup

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .setName("myFakeDB")
            .addScript("my-tables.sql")
            .addScript("my-data.sql")
            .build();


    return db;
}
```

In the my-data.sql I insert data into my table in buckets of 10, so something like

```
INSERT INTO table (column_a, column_b, column_c) VALUES
(...),
(...),
// Do this 10 times total
;
```

Now I've noticed if I have somewhere between 1-1000 records its fine.  But once I surpass that number it dies with the following error:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unknown token: 
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 92 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unknown token: 
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473)
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

Is there a max number of records I can add in a single .sql file?  I have roughly 10,000 records and I would prefer to not have to cap my insert count < 1000 and have 10-11 different .sql files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no maximum record count in HSQLDB.

The error indicates there is a word or symbol in your script file that is not recognised. Check your script to isolate and fix the issue.